# Python/pandas export to excel converted datatime (HH:mm)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, format

I have a problem with xlsx - exported pivot table from pandas.
Everything is fine, except one thing: exported value datas ('job_time') are strings not datatime type.
After getting data into df all columns are object type(including the one with values).
I tried to convert it to datatime type:

```
df['job_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.job_time)
```

It converts this column to datatime, but the format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, where i need HH:MM.
So the next thing i used dt.strftime:

```
df.job_time = df.job_time.dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

It looks good, except one thing: job_time is an object type again.
After export to excel values are text type.

So my question is: what to do to export this data with HH:mm value, but datatime, not text ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['job_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.job_time, format='%H:%M')
df['job_time'] = df['job_time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

Comment: There is a problem with this option: "ValueError: unconverted data remains: :00.0000000". If i add %S.%f to format, then output is 'YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm:ss.0000000'

Comment: Show we part of your data

Comment: `print(df.job_time)

0      08:00:00.0000000
1      08:00:00.0000000
2      08:00:00.0000000`
...

It's bit weird. Data is coming from SQL, where i change time format of job_time from time(7) to time(0).
But it keep showing 7 ms digits.

Comment: After `df['job_time'] = pd.to_datetime`
format is "2020-10-11 08:00:00"
Name: job_time, Length: 357, dtype: datetime64[ns]

Comment: Se updated answer above. I hope this is what you were looking for....

Comment: I already used strftime, as you can see above - it turns job_time into object time, instead of datatime. Format option doesnt work - throwing ValueError.

Comment: Sorry for missed that. What are you trying to do next? Why do you need it as datetime?

Comment: I convert the data into a pivot table and export to Excel and open this file. That's it. The problem is that the data that must be summed in this PivotTable is written as text, not as datetime (HH: mm). The user who will generate this data will not be able to handle it.
Yes, if I use the pd.to_datetime transformation then the data is shown as datetime, but I can't leave it like that - the data must be in Excel. As datetime (actually time) in HH: MM format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222892/discussion-between-gtomer-and-rsj).